# Twilio Recording video chat

Tags: android, web-applications, twilio, twilio-api, videochat

I'm working on twilio video chat between cross platforms,I want to know about recording video chat.Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is currently in developer preview. If you're interested in learning more now, reach out to me directly - mspeir@twilio.com.

You can also keep an eye out on the [changelog](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/changelogs/android) for feature availability.

Comment: I am also working on video chat. but I don know how to implement it. i am getting lots of blogs but there are angular . i am working Aspnet and Jquery. if you can help me please help